# How to get all nodes from Firebase Realtime Database as a list of string

Tags: android, list, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all these nodes (see Image 1 for ref.) from my Realtime Database as a list of String in Kotlin.
Example: ["azd1", "bzi12", "r7", "r8"]

**Image 1** : [image]

Also based on a certain case inside my code I want to access the values inside the particular child. For example I want to access `START_1` of `azd1`
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you need to create a list of all those keys ["azd1", "bzi12", ...]? And what would like to do with that list? Are there nodes in image 1, direct children of the root node?

Comment: Yes they are direct children of the root node. I need that list so I can perform a loop over the elements of that list (basically each node) and compare it with my room database values and then based on it I want to fetch the values from the respective node.

Comment: So will an answer in Kotlin solve your problem, if it'll get all those keys and add them all to a list?

Comment: Kinda yes, I am trying to use event listener to get the values. And I get the desired values in the `dataSnapshot` parameter inside `onDataChanged()` The problem is I am getting all the nodes and their children but I need just the names of the nodes only and add them to a list. Adding them to a list seems like an easy thing if I create a mutable variable and add each node, but what I want is how can I access just the nodes name and not the values. And in the next step inside that loop (which I will create) I want to access that child value inside that node.

Comment: To understand better, you only want the keys (["azd1", "bzi12", ...]) without getting the corresponding data underneath them, right?

Comment: First I want just the keys so I can check which of them matches with the value in my local database. The nodes names (keys) are a subset to the values in local database. So first I want keys and then if a certain key matches based on that I want to fetch the child values inside of it. So basically I want both. But first a list of keys.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the database schema?

Comment: Database schema of Firebase or Local ?

Comment: For the Realtime Database.

Comment: Yes I can do that

Comment: Firebase is a schema-less database.

Comment: How exactly would you like to make the comparison? Since I cannot see anything related to the local database, will an answer that will read the keys help? Besides that, I can provide a more efficient database structure?